# 'constexpr' function strange behavior?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Can somebody explains me how this compiles?

```
constexpr int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b; //Both left Uninitialized as locals

    char arr[Add(a, b)];

    cout << sizeof(arr) << endl;
}
```

It's seems that an array is defined with unknown size as both 'a' and 'b' have unknown value?

Live [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BVTNx4Zqm86sTdNi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The online compiler you show is using `-std=gnu++1y` as a standard, and doesn't use `-pedantic`. That doesn't disable some extensions, notably C99 variable-length arrays (VLAs) that GCC and clang support as an extension.

To get a warning for that, use `-pedantic`. To get an error, use `-pedantic-errors` (or the more general `-Werror`). For this specific extension, `-Wvla` will do it for `g++`, `-Wvla-extension` for `clang++`.

Also prefer `-std=c++1y` rather than the GNU variants to avoid extensions.

clang++:

```
warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
```

g++:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a' [-Wvla]
```

Comment: '-std=C++14' and '-std=C++1z' with the same [result](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mSc2uy0lv3nOZOxZ).

Comment: Yes, you need `-pendantic` as indicated in the second paragraph.

Comment: '$ clang++ prog.cc -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/local/boost-1.56.0/include -I/usr/local/sprout -std=c++14 -pedantic' - are the compiler settings used in above link.

Comment: And I see the warnings. What's the problem? (Add `-Werror` to fail the build.)

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` may be a better match than `-Werror -pedantic` on existing code: it only turns standard-mandated diagnostics into an error, but leaves the rest as a warning.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks, that's indeed better. Updated.